# Does MSK modulation maintain continous phase after spectrum spread?

Tags: modulation, frequency-modulation, spread-spectrum

I need to check if MSK modulation keeps the phase continuous after DS spectrum spread. My thinking is that since we're expanding the bandwidth, it likely involves abrupt frequency changes so it won't keep the phase continous, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: it's not quite clear where your spectrum spreading happens. Could you please describe your system in more detail? Maybe a block diagram that shows what gets spread by which method would help!

Comment: The query in the title of the question asks about constant phase, whereas the question in the body asks about continuous phase.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate My fault. I meant continous, of course. Thanks for noting it.

Comment: @Ketterle to clarify my question: do you do the spreading *before* you do the MSK mapping (so, data -> Direct Sequence -> MSK) or after (so, data -> MSK -> Direct Sequence)

Comment: @Markus Müller. I'm doing the spreading after the modulation so: data -> MSK modulation -> Spectrum spreading. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ketterle hm, so the question is actually whether your spreader keeps the phase continuous, not whether its input does, or am I misunderstanding something? Can you tell us more about what *specifically* you're doing for spreading? DSSS doesn't really define that well enough!

Comment: @Markus Muller. That's right, I need to know whether the spreader keeps the phase continous or not. Imagine I'm spreading the already MSK modulated signal using a Max Length sequence of period 63 (not necessarily a Gold or Kasami code). What I'm asked to clarify is if the spred signal keeps its phase continous or not. I'd bet it does since both logical states (0 and 1) would keep its frequences in a ratio 2:1, but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: @Ketterle if you write my name correctly, I do get notified when you write a comment ;)

Comment: @Ketterle you will please have to tell us what your spreader actually does. We can't tell you. There's more than one way to spread a signal with a code; and your system has taken the slightly strange approach of first doing mapping to an MSK time signal (which only in very specific cases is a linear modulation that happens to map to constellation points!), so you really will have to define exactly what the "spreader" thing is.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with all of this juicy new information about what you're asking.  Stackexchange likes the question to be complete, with only incidentals in the comments.  While you do that, a block diagram -- even if it's scrawled on the back of an envelope and you take a picture of it -- would help.